# spring MVC running cron job

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, cron

How can i run cron job in spring webmvc framework with hibernate..?

Currently I have a application with spring-mvc and hibernate.i need to update the db every day night by calculating data from other tables in database.I have tried by write a java class with main method and run it with linux crontab.but in main method the sessionfactory gives a null instance.i need to done this with in the spring application because all my pojo's and methods are defined in that.i need to use it to calculation.

Comment: You can use [Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation in order to create cron jobs in spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @Scheduled annotation, here is an example :

To enable the @Scheduled annotation in java style

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringConfig {
   ...
}
```

Then annotate the desired method with @Scheduled like this using Cron expresion

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")
public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    System.out.println(
    "schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + now);
}
```

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

Answer (score 1):

Enable scheduling on your application :

```
@EnableScheduling
public class App {
}
```

And use @Scheduled annotation on desired method :

```
@Component
public class MyScheduler {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
    public void myJob() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- For spring-boot example:

  - Annotate your SpringBoot initialzer class with `@EnableScheduling` to enable scheduling:

    `@SpringBootApplication
    @EnableScheduling
    public class HealthVendingMachineApplication {
        ...
    }`
  - Create a method annotated with `@Scheduled` to perform a scheduling task:

    `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)//Or Use @Scheduled(cron='* * * *')
    public void scheduleTaskWithFixedRate() {
    ...
    System.out.println("King in the north... ");
    }`

[ref-link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

- For Spring-Mvc :

  - Create a configuration class to enable scheduling:

    `@Configuration
    @EnableScheduling
    public class SpringConfig {
       ...
    }`
  - Create a component class with methods performing scheduling operations:

    `@Component
    public class MyScheduler {
        ...
        @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
        public void myJob() {
            System.out.println("King in the north... ");
        }
    }`
  - You can use different fields provided by `@Scheduled` annotation. For eg, to schedule job at exactly x=2 seconds use `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)`.

> Edit : I am a beginner in Spring Web Apps development and even though I have tested these examples, kindly correct me if you find anything wrong with this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ContextListener in your application. The listener will automatically call at the time of deployment.

You can below in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.listener.CustomListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Create a class named CustomListener.

public class CustomListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

    if (this.contextLoader == null) {
        this.contextLoader = this;
    }

    this.contextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());



}
   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event){
 }
}
```

ContextInitialized() will get call at time of deployment and contextDestroyed() will get call at undeployment.

You can add your scheduling code inside ContextInitialized() method.

You can use Spring + Quartz for scheduling or Java's Timer class

Timer class implementation will be easy to implement and debug.